# Is this code synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Code below that I try to learn Task class.  From the output, I see the main thread and task thread are running at the same time.  But i get warning message in async method saying that:

"Warning    1   This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."

so then is the code below synchronous?

```
namespace SampleThreadTaskClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            Task task = new Task(ProcessDataAsync);
            task.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter any key");

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + input);

            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }

        static async void ProcessDataAsync()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("processing... " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you misunderstand `async`. It does not mean "make this synchronous method asynchronous".  It means *allow me to use asynchronous waits in this asynchronous method*.  The method has to be *already* asynchronous.  Similarly with `await`. It does not make its argument asynchronous; it identifies a point in an asynchronous workflow where the work must be completed before the workflow continues.

Comment: Yep you are right. I misunderstand the concepts.  I thought after creating Task object and start up the task, it would run another thread independently like background worker thread.

Comment: @Phil please take some time and read [A Tour of Task, Part 1: Constructors - Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Comment: Also, trying to learn about asynchrony in console apps is a very confusing way to begin. Consoles are not naturally asynchronous in the way that GUI applications are.  Try learning in a WPF or Winforms app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is. `Thread.Sleep()` is not asynchronous.

See Explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx#Example

Try delay instead, then you can add an await in front of it,

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ProcessDataAsync` method is indeed synchronous.  It claims to be asynchronous *and it is lying in that claim*.

You then provide that *synchronous* method to the constructor for `Task` which will execute that *synchronous* method in a thread pool thread (which you shouldn't use by the way; if you want to execute a synchronous method in a thread pool thread you should use `Task.Run`).

Of course, for your case you *don't* want to execute this method in a thread pool thread.  You're asynchronous operation is just waiting.  There's no need to schedule a new thread pool thread to just sit there doing nothing for *seconds* at a time.

You should make `ProcessDataAsync` actually be asynchronous, using `Task.Delay` to create a `Task` that will complete in a given interval of time, which you can `await`, and then you can simply call `ProcessDataAsync` when you want to start your asynchronous method and it will *actually be asynchronous*.

Comment: Thanks for your in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What you should try is write some code before starting the task, then start the task in an asynchronous method. Then have another async method like `ProcessDataAsync` use `await` operator in the first async method. This way you can come to know about the async behavior.

This would help

```
static async Task ProcessDataAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            Console.WriteLine("processing... " + i);
        }
    }
```

When you change your return type to `async`, you need to change your call to`ProcessDataAsyc` to this

```
 var task = Task.Run(ProcessDataAsync);
```

And yes your code is async.

Comment: This method shouldn't be `async void` and the calling code would need to be adapted.

Comment: Yes, I agree it should return `Task`. I just kept it `void` because the question had it in that way. `void` should be used only in the case of event handling.

Comment: thanks.  After following your code and link from Alexander Sverla, I understand now.

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html This is one of the best articles about async and await. Go through it for more understanding.